# Boundary components of a subsurface

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology

Consider the following situation. Suppose we have a closed oriented Riemannian surface $ \Sigma $ and a connected open subset $ \Omega \subseteq \Sigma $ with a boundary, consisting of finitely many smooth arcs. Consider a disk $ D $ centered at a point $x \in \Omega $ and denote by $ \Omega_0 $ the connected component of $ \Omega \cap D  $ that contains $ x $.

I wish to relate the number of connected components of $ \partial \Omega $ to the number of connected components of $ \partial \Omega_0 $. Is it true that the first is not less than the latter?

Any comments and references are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Why should this be true? For $D$ sufficiently small, $\partial\Omega_0$ has exactly one connected component, no matter what $\Omega$ is.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear - by a "small" disk, I didn't mean "arbitrary small".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Based solely on the topology:)

Since $\Omega_0$ is connected and contained within the disc $D$, it must be a planar surface, ie. a disc with holes. It has one 'outer' boundary component that is made up at least in part of $\partial D$ (unless $\partial D$ is disjoint from $\Omega$, in which case $\Omega_0=\Omega$), and all other boundary components of $\Omega_0$ are complete boundary components of $\Omega$. Thus $\Omega_0$ could have one more boundary component than $\Omega$ (when $\partial D$ is contained in the interior of $\Omega$) and otherwise it has at most as many as $\Omega$.